# Proper grammar: 生活 中 不是 缺少 美 ，而是 缺少 发现的?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

This grammar page lists the following example:

> 生活 中 不是 缺少 美 ，而是 缺少 发现 美 的 眼睛 。
>
> Shēnghuó zhōng bù shì quēshǎo měi, ér shì quēshǎo fāxiàn měi de
>   yǎnjing.

Would it be correct grammar to omit the 美 and 眼睛? In other words, would the grammar be correct, and the meaning preserved, with this statement:

> 生活 中 不是 缺少 美 ，而是 缺少 发现的

Comment: 生活 中 不是 缺少 美 ，而是 缺少 发现的 seems grammatical, considering 是 缺少 发现的 as 是。。。的 sentence  (in original version 的 played a different role)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't omit 美 and 眼睛, because they are the essential parts for understanding. Without them, the sentence becomes ungrammatical and incomprehensible. Original sentence is saying: *we are not short of things with beauty, but the eye that can discover them.*

Comment: OK thanks. You're saying 眼睛 is the object of 发现 美 like how 車 in 我的車 is the object. What if we wanted to change the meaning slightly to "we are not short of beauty, but of discovery"

Comment: I will comprehend "we are not short of beauty, but of discovery" as 我们不缺少美， 而是我们没有去挖掘。

Comment: re answer: there are 2 美, and only the 2nd is omitted, other users made comments similar to answer, before reading Q more carefully 
they also feel that 而是缺少 **其** 发现 may be possible, which according to Chinese tendency to shorten everything as much as possible might be shortened to proposed 而是缺少发现